# Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my seo friendly url htaccess code?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

It is producing an Error 500 - Internal server error
Thanks very much

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^tmp/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tmp/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: can you please check httpd error_log and see what the actual error is?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern certainly will never match: !^tmp/public, read the documentation: it clearly states that `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains the absolute path, so including a leading slash. So your attempt to prevent an endless rewriting rule fails

Instead match against the absolut path in your condition:

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on        
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ tmp/public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```